# Dispatch Event When Listener Is Added - ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener, dispatchevent

Is it possible to dispatch an event from an object when an event listener is added to that same object, without overriding the addEventListener method of that class?

I am working on a modularized application in AS3.  Several of the modules register events on a component in the main application mxml file.  I would like to fire an event anytime an event is registered to the component from any module, without putting "dispatchEvent(someEvent)" after every addEventListener.

Any input would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: What's the problem with overriding? Seems like the perfect fit here would be to subclass EventDispatcher and to inherit from that.

Comment: Spender, post that as an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built-in that will help you, but you could just write your own function to encapsulate those.

```
public static function addEvent(ed:IEventDispatcher, evt:String, handler:Function) {
  ed.addEventListener(evt, handler, false, 0, true);
  ed.dispatchEvent(new Event("addedEvent"));
}
```